# wordpress function that can be used as wordpress default lost password functionality

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-login

I am creating a web service using PHP of a website which is built in wordpress CMS.
There is a wordpress plugin is used named "Theme My Login" for Registration-Login.

Now I want to know is there any function of wordpress through which I can just pass user email address and wordpress will do lost password functionality?

For login/Registration Functionlity I have included wp-load.php file in my webservice.php file so I can use wordpress user login/register functions in my web service.

my code is as below:

[image]

Is there any function for lost password?
Please guide me for this.

Thank You In advance

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to send `user_login` containing a username or email-adress via `POST` to
`/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword`.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a function you can call to do it, the logic is coded into wp-login.php, but using this hack you can sort of get it to work like a function:

```
<?php

$_POST['user_login'] = 'admin'; // or whatever username / email to send to
$_POST['action'] = 'lostpassword';
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'POST';

require_once 'wp-login.php';
```

Comment: I have tried this way but its not working for me. It doesn't send me any email for reset password. I have attached my code snapshot in my question please take a look on it.

Comment: you need to change your `require_once '../wp-load.php';` to `require_once '../wp-login.php';`